# Unshelving a shelved CL in Perforce to a Different branch

Tags: perforce

I have been trying to unshelve a shelved CL to a different branch in perforce in my workspace. Say the branch name is //streamdepot/child2. This branch is inside my workspace.

Now when i m trying to run the code

p4 unshelve -s 12345 -S //streamdepot/child1 -P //streamdepot/child2
it is showing following error

**Invalid parent field '//streamdepot/child2'. Check stream, parent and type.**

Can someone pls help

Comment: You might need to obfuscate the question less.  Are these streams, or classic branch specs?  Which stream/branch/path are the shelved files in?  If these are streams, is one of them the parent of the other, or are they distantly/wholly unrelated?

Comment: In the simple case, all you should need to do is `p4 unshelve -s 123345 -S //streamdepot/child2` -- but the command will be different if these aren't directly related streams (including if they aren't streams at all).

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue. Resolved my problem by creating a mapping instead, then use:

```
p4 unshelve -s 12345 -b mapping_from_child1_to_child2
```